# Finding maximum subgraph with vertices of degree at most k

Tags: graphs

Let $G = (V, E)$ be an undirected graph and $U \subseteq V$ some subset
of its vertices.  An induced graph $G[U]$ is graph created from $G$ by
removing all vertices that are not part of the set $U$.

I want to find a polynomial time algorithm that has graph $G = (V, E)$
and integer $k$ as input and returns a maximum set $U \subseteq V$ with
largest size such that all vertices of $G[U]$ have degree at most $k$.

My idea with greedy algorithm that removes vertices with largest degree
or vertices connected with most vertices with degree greater than $k$
doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem in polynomial time?

Comment: @PålGD I edited question, is it comprehensible for you now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ be any graph and let $k = 0$.

This problem is, as you correctly pointed out in a comment, better known as [Independent Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) and is famously [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness).

It is therefore unlikely that there is an algorithm solving your problem (which is slightly more general) in polynomial time.

Comment: k and G is an input you cannot let it be whatever you want. Also i don't see how this would answer the question.

Comment: Return largest possible subset of V such that for every (v1, v2) in that subset {v1, v2} is not an element of E. In other words largest set of vertices not connected by edge

Comment: Ok I think I know what you ment by that. It leaves us with NP complete problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)
Thank you for help.